# How do I capture php if/foreach statements in a variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to export the contents of a web page to an Excel doc, but I was using the $contents var to store only the items from the page that I wanted to export.

I am capturing PHP code in a variable to reproduce later when the user clicks a button, but I am having trouble parsing the PHP `if` and `foreach` statements into my variable.

Can anyone tell me how this particular line of code needs to be written in order to be captured for proper display on output?

```
$contents = $contents . '<?php if(isset(' . $detail . ') && is_array(' . $detail . ')){ ?>';
<?php echo $contents; ?>
```

Comment: sounds like an xy problem - you should almost never store code in a variable to run later. tell us what you're trying to achieve. there's probably a better way to do it

Comment: I'll give you the big picture: I am trying to export the contents of a web page to an Excel doc, but I was using the $contents var to store only the items from the page that I wanted to export.  Any ideas?  TIA!

Comment: Use an array to store the data that you want to use later on, don't store the code to execute/find that data - that's unsafe and messy!